# Cannot Wake Laptop From Sleep

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, power-management

I just got a laptop with Windows 8.0 Pro 64 bit. I know this is common problem but I cannot get this solved. When the laptop goes to sleep, it cannot be woken up. I have tried to search google and still cannot get the laptop woken up. There's something strange, when the laptop sleeps caused by the low battery action, it can be woken up, if I press power button or close the lid it cannot be woken up. My previous laptop just works normal with the sleep mode, I can wake it up. I need that sleep mode.

What I've tried is turn off the hybrid boot, change the power options, set the BIOS, reinstall the VGA driver with the latest driver.

In additional my laptop has dual VGA, Intel HD and NVIDIA. Please help me

Comment: IIRC, on low battery it hibernates not sleeps  in that  configuration that can TAKE FOREVER..

Comment: So the solution is to change the power button and lid action to hibernate?

Comment: No, anything BUT hibernate  personally  I have lid close to 'do nothing'  and 'ask' for all otthers